# Orbit and stabilizer

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $g \dot{}x=gxg^{-1}$ for all $g,x\in G.$

Find the orbit and stabilizer when $x=e.$

Orbit: $$G\dot{}x=\{g\dot{}x \ \colon g\in G\}=\{g\dot{}e \ \colon g\in G\}=G$$

Stabilizer: $$G_x=\{g\in G \ \colon g\dot{} x=x\}=\{e\}$$

Is this right?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: No, wrong way round! Orbit is $\{ e \}$, stabilizer is $G$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is thinking that $\cdot$ is group multiplication, when it is in fact conjugation.

For instance, $g\cdot e=geg^{-1}=e$ so the Orbit is $\{e\}$.

$g\cdot e=e$ implies $geg^{-1}=e$ which holds for all $g\in G$, so the stabilizer is $G$.